# Adding an average to an average

Tags: mysql, math, query-optimization

I have a query that is adding an average to an existing average, I have shortned the number of rows being inserted for the example, but typically we are doing 5,000 rows at once many times per day.

```
INSERT INTO stats (impcount, 
                   average_position, 
                   state, 
                   dir_id, 
                   viz_id, 
                   date_date, 
                   org_id, 
                   order_id) VALUES  
('2', '1', '', '5537', '22189', '2014-11-06', '-1', '15963'), 
('2', '2', '', '5624', '22020', '2014-11-06', '-1', '15963'), 
('2', '3', '', '5624', '18215', '2014-11-06', '-1', '15963'), 
('2', '4', '', '6153', '22071', '2014-11-06', '-1', '15963'), 
('1', '9', '', '5624', '21735', '2014-11-06', '-1', '15634')  
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE impcount = impcount + VALUES(impcount),  
average_position = VALUES(average_position) + ((((average_position * impcount) 
+  ( VALUES(impcount) * VALUES(average_position)) ) / (impcount  + VALUES(impcount) ))
- average_position);
```

The table structure is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE stats (
    record_id bigint(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    date_year varchar(4) DEFAULT NULL,
    date_month char(2) DEFAULT NULL,
    date_day char(2) DEFAULT NULL,
    impcount int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
    date_hour varchar(4) DEFAULT NULL,
    dir_id bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
    viz_id int(9) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    order_id int(3) DEFAULT '0',
    date_date date NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00',
    average_position double DEFAULT NULL,
    state varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
    org_id int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (record_id),
    UNIQUE KEY viz_id (viz_id,order_id,date_date,org_id),
    KEY viz_counts (viz_id,date_date,impcount,average_position,order_id),
    KEY daily_counts (date_date,impcount,order_id,average_position),
    KEY dir_counts (dir_id,date_date,order_id),
    KEY org_id (org_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=33499742809 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Does anyone know a way to simplify this, I don't particularly understand the math behind this but was hoping someone might recognize it and know a better/simpler/faster way to accomplish the same thing.

impcount is the amount of impressions each row has and average_position is a straight average of each impression's position. from what I understand this is a rolling average where each on duplicate key update is keeping the average accurate.

Comment: If this works, why do you need to change it?

Comment: it works but its very slow, were continually upserting 5000 or so rows per day with this query - we have other queries with less math getting updated at the same rate that do not have any issue.

Comment: It is highly unlikely that the arithmetic is causing a performance bottleneck on this query.  Can you edit the question and add the table definition?  Also, perhaps the use of string constants where (presumably) you want numbers could be slowing down the query.

Comment: Updated the question with the table structure

Comment: It needs to update 2 keys, which is probably where the time is spent. I don't understand the `VALUES(average_position) + `  starting bit, and the ` - average_position`  ending bit (IMHO, they are _wrong_ and should be omitted, unless I'm missing something), but as Gordon says: that's not likely where your time is spent. The rest is just easy math for a computer: if N times averages M, and X times averages Y, the average of both is `((N*M) + (X*Y))/(M+Y)`. Do supply MySQL with _integers_ or _doubles_ instead of _strings_ when that is what it wants though, there you can win some.

Answer (score 0):

Let A1 and A2 be two averages with counts N1 and N2, respectively. Then the combined average is

```
    N1 × A1 + N2 × A2
A = -----------------
         N1 + N2
```

with count N = N1 + N2.

---

Note that if you store your data as *sums* S1 and S2 and counts N1 and N2, it is a lot easier to do this. The combined sum is S1 + S2, the combined count is N1 + N2, and an average is computed as S / N.